# Getting 'cannot be blank' error on save() because of 'file' validation rule

Tags: php, validation, file-upload, yii2

I got this error when an image file is required: "*Preview cannot be blank*".  Although I filled this field.

My rules:

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        [['name', 'preview', 'date', 'author_id'], 'required', 'on' => 'update'],
        [['name', 'preview', 'date', 'author_id'], 'required', 'on' => 'create'],
        [['date_create', 'date_update', 'author_id'], 'integer'],
        [['preview'], 'file', 'skipOnEmpty' => 'false', 'extensions' => 'png, jpg, jpeg'],
        [['date'], 'safe'],
        [['name'], 'string', 'max' => 255]
    ];
}
```

Controller:

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Book();
    $model->scenario = 'create';
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()) {
        $model->preview = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'preview');
        if ($model->save() && $model->preview->saveAs('uploads/' . $model->preview->baseName . '.' . $model->preview->extension))
        {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        }
    } else {
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

If `preview` file is not required there is no error and the file is being loaded into the `uploads` folder.

Comment: Try with `$model->save(false)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best thing to do here is to avoid using the same field for different purposes.

In your case you are overwriting `preview` with `UploadedFile` instance, you could create another field for this and then:

```
$model->previewFile = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'preview');
```

Then the validation invoked by `save()` won't hit any new issues about `preview` field as the file is held in `previewFile` and original value of `preview` passed through the `$model->validate()` check already.

Comment: $model->preview must contain only file name?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can't make this field required, as it only validates $_POST variables inserted. The file upload is entered in the $_FILES superglobal and not in the $_POST superglobal. Requiring this would mean you want it in your $_POST variables.

You run the validation before handling the file upload. So I would recommend handling the file upload before you handle the model validation, so you can set the value to the model and then run validate afterwards:

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Book();
    $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post());
    $model->scenario = 'create';
    $model->preview = UploadedFile::getInstance($model, 'preview');
    if ($model->validate()) {
        if ($model->save() && $model->preview->saveAs('uploads/' . $model->preview->baseName . '.' . $model->preview->extension))
        {
            return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]);
        }
    } else {
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model,
        ]);
    }
}
```

I didn't test it locally, but making the 'preview' field required without any info in it is not going to work for sure.

P.S. I think it should be 'skipOnEmpty' => false, not with '' around the false.